# "Process-arrow" not showing after breakpoint (Bug/feature request?)

Tags: visual-studio-code

My question is about if this should be reported as a bug or feature request, or is it this way it should be? It is just something I noticed and it does not affect execution of code.
I do not know the name of the "Process-arrow" so I have not been able to search the forum if this has been asked before (sorry for that).

When I start a debug (F5) in VS Code Powershell and I have set a breakpoint, in the taskarea I see a "Process-arrow" showing that the code is executing.

When it hit's a breakpoint the "Process-arrow" disapears, as expected since the execution has stopped.
But if I continue the execution (F5) the "Process-arrow" does not reappear in the taskarea.
See where my pointer is in the attached image.
After it hits the breakpoint I hit F5 and the execution continues until it hits the breakpoint again, but no "Process-arrow" are shown.

Updated with another example, just a simple For-loop. The attached image is still there just to point out what I mean with "Process-arrow"

Add a breakpoint at both Write-Host.
After the first Breakpoint is hit press F5 to continue
The "Process-arrow" is not shown in the taskarea

```
for ($i = 0; $i -lt 10000; $i++) {
write-host $i
if ($i -eq 3758) {
    Write-Host "Breakpoint Here"
}

if ($i -eq 6823) {
    Write-Host "Breakpoint Here"
}
```

}

VS Code info:

- Version: 1.28.0 (user setup)
- Commit: 431ef9da3cf88a7e164f9d33bf62695e07c6c2a9
- Date: 2018-10-05T14:58:53.203Z
- Electron: 2.0.9
- Chrome: 61.0.3163.100
- Node.js: 8.9.3
- V8: 6.1.534.41
- Architecture: x64

[image: circular execution-arrow]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reported this as a bug, https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell/issues/1582, and the response from rjmholt  is that it is likely a a problem with updating the execution status when the debugger is used

Answer (score 0):

This is working as intended. F5 is to continue after the breakpoint. If there is no other breakpoint after, the debug will end as it processed all lines of code.

If you meant to do a RESTART, VSCode's default is CTRL+SHIFT+F5 which will rerun from the beginning.

Comment: Yes, the function F5 is working correctly, as I explained in my question. F5 continues the execution until next time the breakpoint is hit or until finished.
What I am asking is why the "circular execution-arrow" is not shown when I hit F5 after the breakpoint is hit. I do not get any sign that the code is executing or if it is hung/frozen. If you loook at the attached image, you might need to click at it to refresh it, you see where my mousepointer is.

Comment: I understand what you’re talking about now. VSCode is processing something that is taking a long time. Is there anything before your for loop that might take some time to call/process(processing a file/querying AD/DB)? Have you checked what is going on in your call stack?

Comment: I have updated the text and title with "Process-arrow" instead, hope that makes the question more clear. Also added another simple example, a for-loop. After the first breakpoint is hit the Process-arrow is not shown when continuing the execution (F5).

Comment: I don't know if I missunderstand you Peter K, the question is not why it takes time to process. I just reacted to the fact that the "Process-arrow" is not showing after a breakpoint is hit and the execution continues. The "Process-arrow" is giving me a note that the script is still executing but if it is not there, is my script still running or not?

Comment: @AndersNorén that is the point I was trying to make. When executing a script, it should run instantly. So fast, that you should only see the process arrow for a split second. In this case, and in your gif, it shows your script was processing a large amount of data or was hung in a statement. Once it got to the breakpoint, it stopped processing. My question was to see if there was anything being processed that could have taken a while; long enough to see that process arrow?

Comment: Thank you, Yes I am, for learning, doing a check on Office365 accounts against HaveIBeenPwnd. So 400+ accounts gathered first and then each email including alias is checked.

Comment: That would definitely take a bit to process then. Your VS Code is working correctly :)